# putting marker at the ending of line in google-map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i've drawn a line in google-maps using latitude and longitude . also i've put a marker blue.png at the begining of the line.

can anyone please tell me how to put a marker red.png at the ending of line in google-map

**red.png** - http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png

[**http://jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/wLeBh/8/)

My code is as given below

```
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552, 76.327043);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: center,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var polylineCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566, 76.331549),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566, 76.331463),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013503, 76.331313),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013482, 76.331205),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013419, 76.330926),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013334, 76.330712),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013313, 76.330411),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013292, 76.330175),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013228, 76.329854),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013144, 76.329553),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.013059, 76.329296),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012996, 76.329017),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012869, 76.328802),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012785, 76.328545),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012700, 76.328223),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012679, 76.328030),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012658, 76.327837),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012637, 76.327600),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012573, 76.327322),
    new google.maps.LatLng(10.012552, 76.327043)

    ];
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: polylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#FF3300',
        strokeOpacity: 2.0,
        strokeWeight: 5,
        editable: false
    });

    polyline.setMap(map);
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png");
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: polylineCoordinates[polylineCoordinates.length - 1],
        icon: icon,
        map: map,
        clickable: false
    });

}



initialize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue marker that you have added is at the end of the line considering you have used the following line .

```
position: polylineCoordinates[polylineCoordinates.length - 1],
```

This takes the last coordinate from the polyline array.

To add an icon to the start of the polyline you can use.

```
position: polylineCoordinates[0],
```

Added the following code after the blue marker which adds a red marker to the start of polylin.

```
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png");
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: polylineCoordinates[0],
    icon: icon,
    map: map,
    clickable: false
});
```

}

Tested this on the jsfiddle link you provided and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do. Add an array for `markers`. This means that you can manage them properly. Then have a function to create the markers:

```
var markers = [];
var len = polylineCoordinates.length;

markers.push(getMarker('blue', polylineCoordinates[len - 1]));
markers.push(getMarker('red', polylineCoordinates[0]));

function getMarker(type, coords) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'blue':
        var iconUrl = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png";
        break;
      case 'red':
        var iconUrl = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png";
        break;
    }
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(iconUrl),
        map: map,
        clickable: false
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvYwZ/)